# ComponentDidMount() cannot find element when rendered by ReactDOM.render

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm rendering a component with the ReactDOM.render and in the component's componentDidMount, I try to search for an element but, it can't be found.

```
export class ReactComp { 
     public override render() { 
          return (<div id="test"></div>)}

     public override componentDidMount(){
          document.getElementById("test") //error occurs here
     }
}

export class RenderComponent{
   public displayComponent() {
      ReactDOM.render(<ReactComp> </ReactComp>, randomHtmlElement)}
   }
}
```

Why am I unable to find the element? Is it because reactdom.render is not able to display the element fast enough?

Comment: What is the error returned by the function? Is it return `null`?

Comment: Yes it's null. It cannot be found

Comment: I've even tried using refs on the div with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is most likely that you're rendering nothing to the DOM. This is because, in the `ReactDOM.render` function, you only specified what component to render but never told React where to render it.

```js
ReactDOM.render(<ReactComp> </ReactComp>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

You can change the `document.getElementById('root')` with any valid HTML element that exists on the DOM.

Comment: Apologies in my initial example I didn't include the second argument in render

Comment: I tried your code, it works perfectly for me if you start a new project with `npx create-react-app`

Comment: Turns out I was using a node module that would only attach itself to a certain instance.